# Finding $\int\coth^4xdx$

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

$$\begin{align}
\int\coth^4xdx &= \int \coth^2x\cdot \coth^2x dx  \\
&=\int\coth^2x\cdot (\operatorname{csch}^2x-1)dx  \\
&=\int \coth^2x\cdot \operatorname{csch}^2x\cdot dx-\int\coth^2x\cdot dx\\
&=-\int u^2 du - \int \coth^2xdx \\
&=-\frac{\coth^3}{3}-\int (\operatorname{csch}^2x-1)dx  \\
&=-\frac{\coth^3}{3}+\coth^x+x+C
\end{align}$$

My book tells me the right answer is $-\frac{\coth^3}{3}-\coth^x+x+C$

I know this looks like I am nitpicking but I want to make sure I got the identities right. I double checked but can't find the mistake. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: $\coth^2(x) = \operatorname{cosech}^2(x) + 1$, _**not**_ $\coth^2(x) = \operatorname{cosech}^2(x) - 1$. See [this](http://math2.org/math/trig/hyperbolics.htm).

Comment: For the future, you can always go line by line in Wolfram alpha to find your mistake. It can easily check whether any of your asserted equalities are true.

Comment: @an4s thanks...

Comment: @LorenzoNajt That doesn't explain to me what is wrong. Not so great if you aren't so good at this stuff yet

Comment: Well it'll help you narrow down where the mistake is, which is a good first step. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As an4s says, $\coth^2x=\frac{1}{\tanh^2x}$
and 
$\operatorname{csch^2}x=\frac{1}{\sinh^2 x}$, 
$$1+\operatorname{csch}^2x=\frac{1+\sinh^2 x}{\sinh^2x}=\frac{\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x+\sinh^x}{\sinh^2x}=\frac{1}{\tanh^2x}$$
where $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$..

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\int\coth^4xdx &= \int \coth^2x\cdot \coth^2x dx  \\
&=\int\coth^2x\cdot (\operatorname{csch}^2x+1)dx  \\
&=\int \coth^2x\cdot \operatorname{csch}^2x\cdot dx+\int\coth^2x\cdot dx\\
&=-\int u^2 du + \int \coth^2xdx \\
&=-\frac{\coth^3}{3}+\int (\operatorname{csch}^2x+1)dx  \\
&=-\frac{\coth^3}{3}-\coth^x+x+C
\end{align}$$